# CORS node js issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, cors

Having gone through multiple posts on stack I still couldn't find a right answer.

Checked the documentation on [CORS](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#user-content-simple-usage-enable-all-cors-requests) extension as well.

I have the following server code up and running:

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server
var http = require("http")
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
var port = process.env.PORT || 9000

var server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(port)
var count   = 0;
var clients = {};
var rooms   = {};
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server})
wss.on("connection", function(ws) {
    ws.on("create-room", function(data) {
        rooms[data] = {creator : data.user_id, created : new Date()}
    })
    ws.on("close", function() {
        console.log("websocket connection close")
    })
})
```

But I get:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:9000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LE-CbU0. A
>   wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header when the credentials flag is true. Origin
>   'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the
>   withCredentials attribute.

If I comment the line with `app.use(cors());`

I get :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:9000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LE-Cwb8. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

So clearly my server is up and running ok but

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the error message says, the wildcard `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` origin cannot be used with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`. By default, the `cors` module uses a wildward origin, and by default socket.io requires credentials (or so it seems here, anyway). What you need to do is read the `Origin` header of  of the request and include it in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` of the response.

Fortunately, `cors` makes this very easy: in order to reflect the request origin, pass in an options object with an `origin: true` property. You also need a `credentials: true` property to allow credentials at all:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, now I get `Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is '' `

Comment: One question though, now I get 404 when the browser call the url though... If I remove your solution I get the cors error... It's confusing...

Comment: Hi, I read the whole thread but this didn't work for me. Can you look at my question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59679427/cors-validation-for-socket