# Causing The CORS error When Deploying my-app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, error-handling, cors

Access to fetch at 'https://rayaninfosolutions.in/api/MyLogIn' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

ON MY SERVER SIDE I HAVE THIS CONFIGURATION

app.use(cors('https://pathology.rayaninfosolutions.in'));

```
`app.use((req, res, next) => {`

  `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://pathology.rayaninfosolutions.in');`

`  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');`

  `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, content-type');`
` 
  

`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');`
`

 ` next();`
`});`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS node js issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267171/cors-node-js-issue)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your API is the remote domain and you're making a request from localhost.

If that is the case, the domain you need to allow on CORS is the origin (from where the request originates):

```
app.use(cors({
   origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
}))
```